# GCC typeof extension and math on typeof result

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel, typeof

Today I ran across this macro in the Linux kernel (`include/linux/kernel.h`)

```
#define DIV_ROUND_CLOSEST(x, divisor)(          \
{                           \
    typeof(x) __x = x;              \
    typeof(divisor) __d = divisor;          \
    (((typeof(x))-1) > 0 ||  /* <-- why does this work */   \
     ((typeof(divisor))-1) > 0 || (__x) > 0) ?  \
        (((__x) + ((__d) / 2)) / (__d)) :   \
        (((__x) - ((__d) / 2)) / (__d));    \
}                           \
)
```

Now, I understand the purpose of the macro, and that it is somehow leveraging "Statement Expressions" (the link below mentions this).  What I'm not understanding is how `((typeof(x))-1) > 0` amounts to anything useful.  From [this link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) in the gcc docs, I think I understand how the `typeof` extension is meant to be used.  But knowing this doesn't seem to answer how it's used in this macro.  From my own experimentation, `(typeof(x)-1)` doesn't seem to evaluate to anything other than `-1` so isn't this **always** going to be *less than* 0 (i.e. false for the first two parts of the ternary)?

---

If this has already been answered, please point me to it.  I did search but my attempts didn't return a result specific to this usage.

Comment: I suspect it is testing whether the type is unsigned. If `typeof(x)` is some unsigned integer type, then `(((typeof(x))-1)` is positive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not using `(typeof(x)-1)` - it's using `((typeof(x))-1)`, which is of the form `(type)value` - ie, it's a cast expression.

It's casting the value `-1` to the same type as the expression `x`, and then testing if the result is greater than zero.  If `x` has signed integral type or floating point type the result will be false, if `x` has unsigned integral type the result will be true, and for most other types the behaviour will be undefined.

Comment: For most other types the cast will be a constraint violation (requiring a diagnostic). I can't think of any case where this would be undefined behaviour without diagnostic

Comment: @M.M: I believe a pointer type (where it would be comparing two pointers not in the same object using `>`).  It's a little bit silly debating the finer points of the standard here though since the whole construct is an extension.

Comment: Thank you!  I must say, it's so obvious, I should have seen it.  This completely explains why, when I was testing, I had to wrap it in the extra set of parentheses.  It just didn't dawn on me that it was a cast.  I kept trying to "subtract 1" which just wasn't working.  Now, I know why.  Thanks again.